# RSelenium-docker; navigation,checkstatus not working

Tags: r, docker, rselenium

I am new to R. I require using RSelenium for web scraping for my assignment. I am using ubuntu 16.04 and I am trying RSelenium in combination with docker. I am behind a corporate proxy succesfully changed the proxy in docker via adding environment variables manually .I have pulled the image and it is successfully running which I have checked using `sudo docker ps`.
When I am trying to use RSelenium using this code

```
install.packages("RSelenium");library(RSelenium);require(RSelenium);remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost"
                  , port = 4445L
                  , browserName = "firefox");remDr$open(silent=TRUE);remDr$navigate("http://www.google.com");remDr$getTitle()
```

I just get the following output

list()

This list is completely empty.I guess I am missing something very fundamental. Any help will be highly appreciable.

Comment: what image are you using?

Comment: did you check `$ docker-machine ip` ?

Comment: @meatspace I am using Selenium/Standalone-firefox:2.53.0

Comment: @MrSmithGoesToWashington I have checked the docker -machine IP and updated the same in the above code, still getting same results.

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42468831/how-to-set-up-rselenium-for-r