# How to get all the reviews of the apps of Play Store using R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, google-play

I have a dataframe with the urls of all apps I want to get the reviews.
I see that there is a way to do this using Python ([How to perform web scraping to get all the reviews of the an app in Google Play?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58590737/how-to-perform-web-scraping-to-get-all-the-reviews-of-the-an-app-in-google-play)), but I was not able to perform it.
Can I get all the reviews of the apps using R?
I created a code to scroll the webpage, but there are apps with too many reviews. And I want to get the reviews of too many apps.
Thus, scrolling the webpage is not a good way to get all the reviews.

Comment: hi, interesting, was there an error getting the python

Comment: Does this topic anwser your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50987622/web-scrapping-in-r-through-google-playstore?

Comment: No, this way only get 40 reviews. I used the code bellow to scroll and press the "show more" button, but there is an app with 120MM reviews. Thus, this code does not help.

`#scroll down 5 times, waiting for the page to load at each time
for(j in 1:5){      
  remDr$executeScript(paste("scroll(0,",j*10000,");"))
  Sys.sleep(3)    
}

# Locate the load more button
try(loadmorebutton <- remDr$findElement(using = "css selector", ".RveJvd"), silent=TRUE)
try(loadmorebutton$clickElement(), silent=TRUE)

# Wait for elements to load.
Sys.sleep(2)`

Comment: have you tried using the google play api

Comment: I think that I only can get the reviews of my own app by using the google play api, right?