# Web scraping app reviews with R: xpath issues

Tags: r, xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape app reviews from the play and app stores (app name, rating, review text in full, username) and am running into some issues. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50987622/web-scrapping-in-r-through-google-playstore/58947945#58947945) post but ran into a lot of difficulties with RSelenium so I'm wondering if I can do it a simpler way. When using the XPath I am able to get the name of the app, but not the review text or ratings. I'm getting "character(0)" for the User and Review data. Another question I have is that on the Play Store to see more reviews you have to click *Read More* and I'm wondering if the scraping will stop at what is loaded on the page, and if so how to get the full set of reviews.

I have 0 experience with web scraping before today, so sorry if this is obvious.

```
library(rvest)
library(RSelenium) 
library(xml2)
library(stringr)

url <- 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.woebot&hl=en_US'

webpage <- read_html(url)
Name_data_html <- webpage %>% html_nodes(xpath='/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/c-wiz/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/c-wiz[1]/c-wiz[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/c-wiz[1]/h1/span')
Name_data <- html_text(Name_data_html)
head(Name_data)


User_data_html <- webpage %>% html_nodes(xpath='/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/c-wiz[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span')
User_data <- html_text(User_data_html)
head(User_data)

Review_data_html <- webpage %>% html_nodes(xpath='/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/c-wiz[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]')
Review_data <- html_text(Review_data_html)
head(Review_data)

product_data <- data.frame(Name = Name_Data, User = User_data,Review=Review_data)
str(product_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have called RSelenium but you are using rvest commands. These work fine if the website fields you are trying to scrape are not generated using javascript, which is not the case here.