# RSelenium cannot connect to Chrome

Tags: r, selenium-chromedriver, rselenium

I am setting up Selenium in R

```
library(RSelenium)
rD <- RSelenium::rsDriver(browser="chrome")
```

When i run `rsDriver()`, it brought up chrome and gave the following errors

```
[1] "Connecting to remote server"

Selenium message:unknown error: unable to discover open pages
  (Driver info: chromedriver=71.0.3578.33 (269aa0e3f0db08097f0fe231c7e6be200b6939f7),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 60.99 seconds
Build info: version: '3.141.5', revision: 'd54ebd709a', time: '2018-11-06T11:58:47'
System info: host: 'ELI-T460', ip: '172.xx.xx.xx', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Could not open chrome browser.
Client error message:
     Summary: UnknownError
     Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
Check server log for further details.
```

I have tried to run with older version of chromedriver and it gave the same error.

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42468831/how-to-set-up-rselenium-for-r