# Scrape dynamically-generated webpage in R without needing to download Docker

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

I am trying to scrape a table of legislators from the following website: https://www.legis.ga.gov/members/house

First I tried Rvest, but that did not work because the page is dynamically generated.

```
library(rvest)
url <- 'https://www.legis.ga.gov/members/house'
page = read_html(url)
page %>% 
  html_element("table") %>%
  html_table()

#Error in View : no applicable method for 'html_table' applied to an object of class "xml_missing"
```

Then I tried RSelenium. That did not work because it could not determine server status.

```
library(RSelenium)
rD = rsDriver(browser="chrome", port=4234L, chromever="109.0.5414.74")

#Warning message:
#In rsDriver(browser = "chrome", port = 4234L, chromever = "109.0.5414.74") :
#  Could not determine server status.

library(wdman)
selServ <- wdman::selenium(verbose = FALSE)
selServ$log()

#$stderr
#[1] ""
#
#$stdout
#[1] ""
```

Then I tried to install the Splash package. I got this warning:

"Warning in install.packages :
package ‘splashr’ is not available for this version of R"

Looking at other Stackoverload questions, several suggest downloading something called Docker (e.g., [How to set up rselenium for R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42468831/how-to-set-up-rselenium-for-r)). But it looks like this will then involve launching Docker and doing several complicated steps each time I need to scrape something. It doesn't make sense to go through all those steps to scrape a single table. I'm also leery of downloading software if it's not necessary. What is the simplest way to scrape this table? Am I missing something obvious that I was supposed to do?

For reference: I am using Chrome version 109.0.5414.119 on macOS Ventura, R Version 4.2.0.

Comment: Not sure if you are using Rstudio or not, but I get that message a ton within Rstudio, but when I attempt the same installation outside of Rstudio, it works fine. Then I go back in Rstudio call library(mypackage), and it works fine...

Comment: Here's a fairly thorough blog post of a step-by-step with rselenium: https://appsilon.com/webscraping-dynamic-websites-with-r/

Comment: I am working in RStudio. Are you referring to the installation for Splash? It looks like Splashr was removed from the cran repository (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/splashr/index.html), so does it make sense to try to install it another way? Not sure how I would do that. 
The steps in the blog post don't work for me because I still get the "Could not determine server status" error when I try to specify a chrome version.

Answer (score 1):

Sniff their API from th network section and call on it with `httr2`

```
library(httr2)
library(tidyverse)

"https://www.legis.ga.gov/api/members/list/1031?chamber=1" %>% 
  request() %>%
  req_auth_bearer_token("eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYmYiOjE2NzU3OTY4NDgsImV4cCI6MTY3NTc5NzE0OCwiaWF0IjoxNjc1Nzk2ODQ4fQ.3pxxIurHe8uPgXGY0DZay0wAUk8Lf5rbHsGvXiNbYMY") %>% 
  req_perform() %>% 
  resp_body_json(simplifyVector = TRUE) %>% 
  as_tibble() 

# A tibble: 178 × 13
   district$id party photos lastName  districtNumber city     fullName sessionId    id name$first
         <int> <int> <list> <chr>              <int> <chr>    <chr>        <int> <int> <chr>     
 1          59     0 <df>   Adesanya              43 Marietta Solomon…      1031  5025 Solomon   
 2         158     0 <df>   Adeyina              110 Grayson  Segun A…      1031  5044 Segun     
 3          99     0 <df>   Alexander             66 Hiram    Kimberl…      1031   806 Kimberly  
 4          12     1 <df>   Anderson              10 Cornelia Victor …      1031  4989 Victor    
 5          54     0 <df>   Anulewicz             42 Smyrna   Teri An…      1031  4915 Teri      
 6          72     0 <df>   Au                    50 Johns C… Michell…      1031  4983 Michelle  
 7         203     1 <df>   Ballard              147 Warner … Bethany…      1031  5051 Bethany   
 8          29     1 <df>   Ballinger             23 Canton   Mandi B…      1031   808 Mandi     
 9         132     0 <df>   Barnes                86 Tucker   Imani B…      1031  5037 Imani     
10          30     1 <df>   Barrett               24 Cumming  Carter …      1031  5020 Carter    
# … with 168 more rows, and 11 more variables: district$number <int>, $chamberType <int>,
#   $suffix <chr>, name$last <chr>, $middle <chr>, $nickname <chr>, $suffix <chr>,
#   $familyName <chr>, districtAddress <df[,8]>, residence <chr>, dateVacated <lgl>
```

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you! I right-clicked on the API page and saved it as georgia_house.json. Then the only code I had to write was: 
library(jsonlite)
house = fromJSON("./data/georgia_house.json")
However, using httr2 didn't work for me. How do I get a req_auth_bearer_token?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I did not need to scrape this page at all, because the data was available as a JSON in the network section. However, I was able to find out how to get around the RSelenium server status error. I simply had to set the Chrome version to NULL.

```
    driver <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox",
                           chromever=NULL,
                           verbose = FALSE)
```